# docker-compose как загрузить дамп базы только 1 раз?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Необходимо сохраниыть докер образ в файл и потом передавать их "на проверку" на флешке.
Образ с базой данных должен содержать накаченный дамп.

Пробую собирать образ из Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:12.4-alpine
ADD ./dump/dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

А потом запускаю это всё через docker-composel:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: my_custom_image
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:5432
```

Проблема заключается в том, что дамп накатывается каждый раз при старте контейнера, что ведёт например к тому что остальные контейнеры могут не дождаться накатки дампа и упасть по таймауту подключения к бд.

Как можно накатить дамп 1 раз, чтобы при старте контейнера с базой все данные были уже заполнены?

Вернее так - как сделать образ, чтобы он уже содержал уже накаченный дамп? Чтобы соответственно человек подниал контейнер из этого образа и в контейнере уже была бы заполненная база.

Comment: создать дамп, который будет проверять наличие таблицы/данных и не будет ничего делать?

Comment: Во время сборки образа вместо `ADD ./dump/dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` запустить постгрес и выполнить восстановление.

Comment: + а что крутится в "остальных контейнерах" которые падают?

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov там node.js приложение с typeorm и @nestjs/typeorm. Оно не то что падает - оно может упасть если дамп накатится позже чем закончатся попытки реконнекта. У меня на компе чаще взлетает чем не взлетает. Но как оно будет на компьютере человека который это будет запускать - фиг знает. Вопрос короче в том - как сделать образ, в котором уже будет нужный дамп.

Comment: Самый простой способ не разбираясь в устройстве образа и как там накатывать дамп, это запустить один раз, дождаться окончания загрузки дампа, можно удалить `dump.sql`, остановить контейнер, потом `git tag` - и у вас готовый образ с данными. Используйте вместо `my_custom_image` в compose файле. Более "правильный" способ, это найти команду которая запускается после старта контейнера, и ее запускать из Dockerfile, чтоб то, что происходит при старте, сделалось один раз при сборке.

Comment: @RomanKonoval стартануть контейнер а потом тэгнуть его - мне это нравится :)

Answer (score -1):

Выполнить накат дампа в процессе сборки контейнера? Или развернуть дамп локально и скопировать каталог данных в контейнер. И при старте это уже не нужно будет.

Если же такой вариант не возможен, то при старте других контейнеров можно учесть время развертывания БД, например до одной минуты. и добавить это в entrypoint.sh

```
sleep 1m
java -jar ...
```

Comment: я не минусовал...

Comment: @muturgan не парься :)